# How to append select query results in a QTextEdit panel?

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite

I'm work in a project where I need to execute a select query(I use sqlite as a sql engine) and load the result into a QTextEdit(I use QT for my graphical interface).
For now I wrote only the following code(but I stuck in the part where I need to append the result to the QTextEdit):

```
//Callback function to print the query to the console
int db_files::CallBack(void *notUsed, int argc, char **argv, char **azColName) {
    for(int i = 0; i<argc; i++) {
        printf("%s : %s\n", azColName[i], argv[i] ? argv[i] : "NULL");
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
    return 0;
}

//Function where I open the database and run the query
void custHandler::show_all() {
     rc = sqlite3_open("database.db", &db);
     if(rc != SQLITE_OK) {
          sqlite3_close(db);
          exit(1);
      }
      sqlCust = "SELECT * FROM DB";
      rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sqlCust, CallBack, 0, &ErrMsg);
      if (rc != SQLITE_OK) {
          exit(1);
      }
      sqlite3_free(ErrMsg);
      sqlite3_close(db);
}
```

Maybe I need to operate in the callback function, but I don't know how ... someone can explain it to me?

EDIT:
I have a QTextEdit variable called txtShow, i usually access it by `ui->txtShow.insertPlainText("text");`

Comment: Could you please format the code properly with indentation so we can read easily? Moreover, there is no QTextEdit anywhere in your code so we can not know where to append. Am I right to assume that you want to append what you printf to the terminal in a QTextEdit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the synopsis of the `sqlite3_exec()` function in the [SqlLite documentation](https://sqlite.org/c3ref/exec.html):

> ```
> int sqlite3_exec(
>   sqlite3*,                                  /* An open database */
>   const char *sql,                           /* SQL to be evaluated */
>   int (*callback)(void*,int,char**,char**),  /* Callback function */
>   void *,                                    /* 1st argument to callback */
>   char **errmsg                              /* Error msg written here */
> );
> ```

As you see the 4th parameter is a user defined argument that will be passed to the `callback()` function.

So you'll need to use that too interact with your calling code:

```
//Callback function to print the query to the console
int db_files::CallBack(void *myQTextEdit, int argc, char **argv, char **azColName) {
    QTextEdit* qTextEdit = (QTextEdit*)myQTextEdit;

    for(int i = 0; i<argc; i++) {
        // Add the results to qTextEdit as needed ...
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When calling the `sqlite3_exec()` function pass that:

```
//Function where I open the database and run the query
void custHandler::show_all() {
     rc = sqlite3_open("database.db", &db);
     if(rc != SQLITE_OK) {
          sqlite3_close(db);
          exit(1);
      }
      sqlCust = "SELECT * FROM DB";
      rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sqlCust, CallBack, &myQTextEdit, &ErrMsg);
                                            // ^^^^^^^^^^^^

      if (rc != SQLITE_OK) {
          exit(1);
      }
      sqlite3_free(ErrMsg);
      sqlite3_close(db);
}
```

That's a very common way how C-style API's interact with user code in callback functions.

Comment: I've got two error running your code: the first is the conversion from void to QTextEdit(in the callback function)...it seem that there isn't a method to do that cast.   The second problem is that in the fourth argument(in the sqlite3_exec function) the &myQTextEdit isn't recognized...

Comment: @zDoes _"&myQTextEdit isn't recognized"_ You have to put the name of your `QTextEdit` control member there of course. You can't expect that you take my example and it runs right out of the box. It was just to explain you the principle how that works.

Comment: Thanks, i didn't see it...but in the callback function the QTextEdit* qTextEdit = (QTextEdit)myQTextEdit; still generate the cast error...

Comment: @zDoes Sorry, that was a typo in my example, should be: `(QTextEdit*)myQTextEdit;`.

Comment: Thanks! Your solution works...you saved my project! :D